# Access to object property with variable

Tags: javascript, object

Hello so basically I wonder how I can achieve to select property from object with:

`objectName.someVariable`.

For example how to make [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/6lQWsuSldomSaCVLEL9e?p=preview) code `console.out`ing number from object:

```
var a = function(selected){
  console.log(selected);
    var q = {
    black: 1,
    red: 2,
    blue: 3
  }
  console.log(q.selected);
  console.log(q+'.'+selected);
}
```

Comment: This is currently very unclear.

Comment: What is so unclear? Just take a look at code no words needed.

Comment: @BT101 If it isn't unclear, why can't you figure it out yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: No words needed? So you honestly think SO is full of people who just read explanationless code and try to guess what the problem might be? If you want help, help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to an object property with:

- a point like this: `q.black`
- with two [] like this : `q.["black"]` or `q.[aVariable] //aVariable  = "black"`

In your example, you can simply do like this:

```
var a = function(selected){
  console.log(selected);
    var q = {
    black: 1,
    red: 2,
    blue: 3
  }
  console.log(q.selected);  // Serve to nothing.
  console.log(q[selected]+'.'+selected);
}
```

You can consult [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp) if you want more details.

*Tell me if you have some questions.*